# How to add different installation profiles in drupal 7

Tags: theming, installation

I have my own custom built theme. I want to add installation profile like many premium themes have. Is this is achievable by any module?

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the [Profiler Builder](http://drupal.org/project/profiler_builder) module:

> Profiler Builder is an extension of the [Profiler](http://www.drupal.org/project/profiler) installation profile simplifier. This module creates a downloadable tar package that gives you a well made installation profile and associated drush make file based on the site its installed on. This is a fast, simple way of creating a distribution with options that take into account either local host development or drupal.org packaging scripts.